# Select only one number from array MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following query bellow

```
SELECT * FROM subcat where catid in (2) order by id desc
```

what i am trying to do is select one number only in catid i have ex:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

this work but only when "catid" start with number "2" then have ","

example

```
ID | 1
subcat_name | PHP
catid | 2,3,4

ID | 2
subcat_name | ASP
catid | 5,2,3

ID | 3
subcat_name | MYSQL
catid | 6

ID | 4
subcat_name | C++
catid | 2
```

i want to select the subcat with only `catid = 2`

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: I must have read this 10 times, and I still don't get it.

Comment: NORMALIZE! NORMALIZE! NORMALIZE!

Comment: sure but first sorry about my english :(
look i have a category system and subcategory 
there is some subcategory are in more than 2 or 3 category at the same time and some subcategory are in one category only
so when i use this method to select multi subcategory it's work but when i am trying to select only one id it's work when the catid start with the same number where i select 
in the next comment i will post an example

Comment: Then you could probably add a `LIKE` to it, checking for exact number. I.e.: `LIKE %2%` - Yet as Mark stated, you need to Normalize.

Comment: %2% will get him 12 and 27 and 123 and any number has 2 in it, I think what he wants is @Wilmer solution

Comment: I thought that `%2` would get the OP `21` `25` etc. @CodeBird which is why thinking in wrapping with 2x `%` would make a perfect match, no? But I think you're right about Wilmer's answer; it makes sense.

Comment: if he wants to do it with like % he should use (like %,2,% or like 2,%) this way he gets only 2's

Comment: i've already try to use like but give me another query where catid don't = 2 :(

Comment: @MarkBaker: [NORMALIZE!](http://merchandise.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/dalek-580.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM subcat where FIND_IN_SET(2,catid) order by id desc
```

Comment: it's give me an error 'FUNCTION dbname.FIELD_IN_SET does not exist'

Comment: pardon me it's FIND_IN_SET not FIELD_IN_SET. I updated the reply.

Comment: Don't worry Thank You verry much it's worked finaly :D